# Dog randomly trying to lick pee

Tags: dogs, behavior

My 3-year-old non-fixed male dog has randomly started to lick anything with dog urine on it.

His fixed 4-year-old male dog brothers paws, penis, the floor where he walks after coming in and trying to hump him. I left today and when I came home he has peed on his brothers face and the kitchen floor *(believe to be humping his brothers face)*. Has never done anything like this and I'm wondering if its health issue because I'm due with our first child in 2 weeks and want my boys to be healthy before baby arrives.

He doesn't seem to be in any pain eats, drinks, pees and poops outside regularly and also sleeps his night without issue but will constantly follow his brother around trying to lick anything with pee smell.

Comment: I'm assuming your question is how to prevent this behaviour. Could you maybe edit this into your post if it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

It could be any number of things but I suspect that it is some combination of :

- the 3 year old being the leader and exerting dominance (humping) on his brother, especially if the 4 year old is submissive or if they are meeting at your (the 3 year old's) house/territory. Sometimes once dogs gain confidence, they begin humping a lot, and it can happen like a light switch.
- the 4 year old having some sort of health issue and the 3 year old trying to "help" out and/or hide/cover his smell
- some sort of dietary deficiency in the 3 year old causing him to find what he needs in his friend's urine
- the changes in your body and hormones as your baby gets ready
- dogs will also act unpredictably when a bitch in heat is nearby

I don't like sending people to the vet unnecessarily but I think a vet trip is in order for both dogs.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior might be caused by the hormones your body is producing during pregnancy.

[AnimalWised](https://www.animalwised.com/why-does-my-dog-lick-urine-of-other-dogs-1647.html) explains that dogs have a special sensory organ:

> [T]he vomeronasal organ, also known as Jacobson's organ. This organ is located in the vomer bone, between the mouth and the nose of the dog and is responsible for transmitting information to the brain.
>
> Jacobson's organ is responsible for analyzing large molecules, such as pheromones and other compounds. This plays a crucial role in hunting, reproduction, the perception of environment or the social relationships of dogs. It is therefore a fundamental organ for dogs to decipher information related to other dogs such as their food, **sex or estrous cycle.**

Urine has a strong smell, especially for dogs. A female dog would excrete high amounts of hormones with her urine when she gets into heat. Male dogs would examine the urine with their Jacobson's organ to check whether the female is conception ready. This automatically increases the hormone production in the male as well, making him more dominant and ready to fight for the big prize.

Your dog might be reacting to *your* hormones or pheromones and constantly checking the urine of your female dog to see when she is conception ready. **This all is perfectly natural and instinctual behavior.**

I suggest you keep an eye on both dogs during the next days and weeks. Check their weight to be sure they're not loosing weight and keep an eye on how much they eat and drink.

**If your female loses weight or drinks much more than usual, she could have diabetes**, which makes her urine taste sweet. If you see any unusual behavior or weight loss, please see a vet.